# QProcess claims process exited when process is still running

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I am starting an external GUI application in Linux from a `QThread`, using a `QProcess`. The process successfully enters the starting state (`QProcess::Starting`), then enters the running state (`QProcess::Running`), but then, just afterward, enters the stopped state (`QProcess::NotRunning`, verified by a slot connected to the `stateChanged(QProcess::ProcessState)` signal). `QProcess::errorString()` returns "Unknown error." The external process is still running, but the `QProcess` object doesn't show it as running.

This happens with most applications, but I have found that Dolphin file manager and xterm do not exhibit this behavior. It's possible there are others that work as well. I am using Qt 5.4.0 with Debian 8.2 Jessie, GCC 4.9.2.

Does anyone know why this would happen? Unfortunately, I am unable to post a complete example, as that would require posting nearly the entire application.

```
class RecordingControllerObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    RecordingControllerObject(QObject *parent = 0)
        : QObject(parent)
        ...
        , proc(new QProcess(this))
        ...
    {
        ...
        connect(proc, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QProcess::ProcessState)), SLOT(procStateChanged(QProcess::ProcessState)));
        ...
    }
    virtual ~RecordingControllerObject()
    {
        ...
        if (proc->state() == QProcess::Running)
        {
            proc->terminate();
            proc->waitForFinished(-1);
        }
        delete proc;
        ...
    }

    ...

signals:
    ...

public slots:
    ...

    void startWatcher(const QString &program, const QStringList &arguments)
    {
        qDebug("starting watcher\n");
        if (proc->state() == QProcess::Running)
            proc->kill();
        proc->start(program, arguments);
    }

private slots:
    void readyRead(const QByteArray &buffer)
    {
        if (proc->isOpen())
            proc->write(buffer);
    }

    void procStateChanged(QProcess::ProcessState state)
    {
        std::cout << "proc state changed: " << state << std::endl;
        std::cout << "proc error: " << proc->errorString().toUtf8().constData() << std::endl;
    }

    ...

private:
    ...
    QProcess *proc;
    ...
};
```

Comment: Have you tried starting another app, like plain xterm?

Comment: Also, connect all signals of QProcess to a debug slot or lambda and print any error/status/result codes they get, if you don't already catch them all.

Comment: If it does happen with all apps, then create a minimal example which reproduces the problem, and add it to the question (or if you fail reproducing it, then figure out what is the difference with real ap and the working minimal example you created).

Comment: ... I hope you're not using a `QThread` just for starting a `QProcess` ?

Comment: @peppe - No. The thread actually is a timed controller for another thread, and needs to run an external process.

Comment: I would recommend upgrading to 5.5, many QProcess bugs have been fixed in the meanwhile. Preventing further problems: are you connecting the `QProcess`(created from the new thread)' signals to slots added on top of the `QThread` object?

Comment: @hyde - After some tweaks, I managed to get it working with xterm, but the `QProcess` still immediately "finishes" (while the external process lives on) with something like thunar or konsole. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post a piece of code where you create and monitoring the process?

Comment: @peppe - The same behavior is exhibited in Qt 5.5.1. Only xterm (of the applications I have tried) is seen by the `QProcess` as still running.

Comment: Check if the PID of the observed application process actually stays the same before and after QProcess reports that its stopped (maybe there’s some forking going on?). And what do you mean by "stopped state”? “NotRunning”? (see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#ProcessState-enum)

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld - The PID is the same when the `QProcess` reports it is running as it is when the `QProcess` reports it is stopped. As for the question, yes, I mean that the `QProcess::state()` returns 0, or `QProcess::NotRunning`.

Comment: 1. You told about `QThread`, but there is no `QThread` using in your piece of code. 2. If you use  async method `QProcess::start()`, why do you need to use `QThread` ? 3. Are you sure that your signal-slots interaction connections between the threads (if the threads are exist) are correct? Do you use `Qt::QueuedConnection` ?

Comment: @VladimirBershov - The entire shown class is running in a non-GUI `QThread`. Yes, I am using `Qt::QueuedConnection` to communicate between threads, and the cross-thread communication is working fine right now.

Comment: @owacoder, You need to create a very simple basic working version, as simple as possible, in order you could be shure that it doesn't contain mistakes. Of course, it must not contain additional threads. Then you have to make sure that it works, and begin to add a desired functionality step-by-step.